# Should I declare a variable inside or outside the main function?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, variable-declaration

In C++, it is advisable to declare global variables inside the main program, or outside it, before everything else? I mean, what is the difference between

```
#include <iostream>

int variable;

int main()
{    //my program
     return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int variable;
     //my program
     return 0;
}
```

In which case should I use which one?

Comment: You should almost never declare variables outside of functions. It's a bad practice that leads to questionable designs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I do not neccessarily agree with duplicate. OP seems to be asking 'which is which', not 'which is better'. From the question itself it is not clear if OP understands what the global variable is. voting to reopen.

Comment: @n.m., care to say that to STL implementors?

Comment: @SergeyA not sure what you mean.

Comment: @n.m. He refers to stuff like  `std::cout` aso.

Comment: @n.m. I mean, that there are several global variables in there. Is it a *bad design*?

Comment: @πάντα yes, I very much dislike how standard streams remember state across function invocations. Personally, I also dislike the very concept of standard streams, independently of the language.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I would say it is a bad design, in most cases.

Comment: @n.m., OK, point taken. How would you design a console output mechanism?

Comment: @SergeyA: I/O streams have nothing to with the "STL", nor with the containers/iterators/algorithms part of the standard library.

Comment: @SergeyA why not open and close these streams like any other files?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, the second part is both moot and wrong. It is moot because it is not relevant (not being part of stl algorithms has nothing to do with being part of STL), and it is wrong because there is a stream iterator. So it is part of iterators. The second part is also wrong, unless you can provide some proof. (STL means STandard Library for long time)

Comment: @n.m, and pass the stream object through the whole program? What would be the benefit?

Comment: @SergeyA: The stream iterator *uses* the library. It's not part of the library itself. As for the name "STL": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571

Comment: @ChristianHackl, like I said, they are part of the same library. If you can support your claim using **standard** as a reference, I am open to discussion, otherwise there is no sense in continuing it.

Comment: @SergeyA no, open them when you need them, close when you are done. Passing them as paraeters to every function doesn't make a lot of sense. Though for objects that exist outside of the program, like standard streams, global handles are often convenient and not that problematic.

Comment: @n.m.. but how would you open them? What would be the argument to a function which returns any handle representing console output?

Comment: @SergeyA: `std::istream_iterator` and `std::ostream_iterator` are indeed part of the iterator library (section 24), but they are completely generic and not tied to standard I/O streams. As far as I see it, the only reference to `std::cin` and `std::cout` in that section is in an example in §24/6(1). The design and implementation of what you call "STL" does not require any global objects.

Comment: @SergeyA There are special names around like /dev/null and many others, they could have used something similar.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, what I (an many others) call STL is the library described in C++ Standard. This library uses global objects.

Comment: @n.m., where would this name come from? Will it be a **global variable** or a magic word ("gimme the console, please?"). Also, you can globally tie `cout` to `cerr`, replace the buffer of `cout`, (effectively redirecting it transparently to other callers), possibly do other stuff. How would all this work when you just request a new object every time?

Comment: @SergeyA /dev/null is a magic word and nobody seems to have any problem with that. So is "file descriptor 0" in the Unix world (it's just an integer 0). I'm not quite sure why you think other callers will necessarily appreciate your fiddling with *their* cout. The ability of *every* function to pull such tricks is precisely the reason why I dislike it.

Comment: A variable declared in main is automatic, not global.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the first case `variable` is accessible from all other functions in the file (i.e. it has global scope) whereas in the second case it is only accessible from within `main`. Generally, it's best to keep the amount of global variables you use to an absolute minimum to avoid polluting the variable space (among several other reasons).

Example:

Local to main,

```
int main(void) {
    int v;
    foo();
    return 0;
}

void foo() {
    v = 5; // compiler error: v not declared in this scope
}
```

Global,

```
int v;
int main(void) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}

void foo() {
    v = 5;   // compiles, v declared globally
}
```

Comment: The suggestion is right, but the reason (polluting the variable space) is probably low in the list of reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused between a global variable, and a local variable in the main which still is local.

Comment: *In the first case variable is accessible from all other functions in the file (i.e. it has global scope) whereas in the second case it is only accessible from within main.* **Main** in here is **main()**, I believe. Is any possibility to write a code without involving this **main()**. Unless we are writing a function or using another function other that **main()** function, then your answer is correct. As I understood, the **main()** will always global. Thereby, the claim seems is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

`variable` in first case is a *global variable*. It can be accessed from functions other than, and including,  `main()`; is guaranteed to live until program executes; and is set to 0 before first use.

In the second example, `variable` is a function local variable. It is not initialized to anything unless set by the programmer, can only be accessed within `main()`, and will be obliterated before `main()` terminates. That last point is not especially important for `main()`, but is much more important for other functions.